# How do I replace

Tags: r, csv

Right now I am working on a program to compare lists of keywords.  The basic idea is to construct a list of keywords and their associated frequencies from CSV files, and then compare those keywords to a master list.

The problem I am having is replacing the frequencies with the right number from the CSVs.  I think it's best to see this by looking at how the CSV files are structured.  For example,

```
File 1
------
car,5
house,6
bee,30
gator,10

File 2
------
jump,4
bee,20
go,9
bike,24
fence,31
might,20

Master
------
students,8
statistical,8
excel,6
mathematics,6
sas,6
student,5
report,5
washington,5
analysis,5
course,5
performance,4
pages,4
university,4
improve,4
using,4
```

Note that in my code since the files aren't alphabetized, the frequencies are not being replaced correctly.

When I run my code shown below, this is the output:

```
 Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, which(as.character(keywords$keywords)     %in%  :  replacement has 6 rows, data has 5
```

Here is my code, the error starts on the line after "keywordmax=as.data.frame(c("0"))"

```
agg=function()
{
# Read in individual data sets
key1=read.csv("set1.csv",header=FALSE,sep=",")
key2=read.csv("set2.csv",header=FALSE,sep=",")
master=read.csv("master.csv",header=FALSE,sep=",")
exclude_list=read.csv("exclude.csv",header=FALSE,sep=",")

# Sort, capitalize, and keep unique values from the two keyword sets
keywords <- sapply(unique(sort(c(as.character(key1$V1), as.character(key2$V1)))), toupper)

# Keep keywords greater than 2 characters in length (basically exclude in at etc...)
keywords <- keywords[nchar(keywords) > 2]

# Keep keywords that are not in the exclude list
keywords <- setdiff(keywords, sapply(exclude_list, toupper))

# Compare the read keyword list to the master keyword list
# and keep the frequency column

key1$V1=sapply(key1[[1]], toupper)
key2$V1=sapply(key2[[1]], toupper)
master$V1=sapply(master[[1]], toupper)

keywords=as.data.frame(keywords)
keywordmax=as.data.frame(c("0"))
keywords[which(as.character(keywords$keywords) %in% as.character(key1$V1)),2]=key1[,2]
keywords[which(as.character(keywords$keywords) %in% as.character(key2$V1)),3]=key2[,2]
keywords[which(as.character(keywords$keywords) %in% as.character(master$V1)),4]=master[,2]

keywords[is.na(keywords)] = 0
keywordmax=keywords[,2:3]
keywordmax=apply(keywordmax, 1, max)
masterset=keywords[,4]

keywords=keywords[,1:2]
keywords$V2=as.data.frame(keywordmax)
keywords$V3=as.data.frame(masterset)

return(keywords)
}
```

Comment: you didnt include `exclude_list `. I'm still not sure what you're trying to do. what do you want `agg()` to return when finished?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: I am trying to merge the two files, sort and capitalize them, and keep their associated frequencies, then compare that list to the master list.